# Jooq operator precedence

Tags: jooq

I would like to create sql expression in JOOQ:

> a OR b AND c

But I cannot find a way to do that, when combining conditions in JOOQ:

> a.or(b).and(c)

It always be (a OR b) and C. I know why, but how can I achieve to not do this?

I wouldnt like to concat it in String. (thats the only solution what I have found so far.)

Comment: Doesn't `a.or(b.and(c))` work?

Comment: It is, but I need to do it dynamic, its a list and can contain any number of condtions in random order with OR, AND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```java
a.or(b).and(c);
```

Then you're really writing:

```java
var c1 = a.or(b);
var c2 = c1.and(c);
```

This is just Java, it doesn't have anything to do with jOOQ, strictly speaking. So, if you want to give higher precedence to the right operand of your `OR` predicate, write

```java
a.or(b.and(c));
```

Think about it again this way:

```java
var c1 = b.and(c);
var c2 = a.or(c1);
```

Again, this isn't related to jOOQ, it's just Java code. And as you can see, [jOOQ queries are always dynamic](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), irrespective of whether you make them look like ordinary SQL (by writing them using the fluent API), or whether you assign parts of your query to local variables, or return them from functions. It's all the same to jOOQ.

Comment: I see, but dont it have some method/function where I can add all of the conditions to the same level? It have a solution if everything needed to add as AND. Problem is I need to write this:
var c1 = a.or(b);
var c2 = c1.and(c);

I would like to write this: .where(conditionOR, conditionAND, conditionOR etc..)

Comment: It has a function where(Condtion...condtion) but it says it ANDs everything together.

Comment: Use `DSL.or(Condition...)` or use `Stream.reduce` with `Condition::or`, or whatever.

Comment: But I would like to mix OR and AND conditions, DSL.or(Condition...) OR-s everything together

Comment: @ZoltánRaffai: Can you please be more specific about what you want, *exactly*? Your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: So I have a list of conditions which contains pair<And, a>, <Or, b>, <And, c>, <Or, d>, <And, e>, <And,f>. I would like to create one condition from it where all are just next to each other on same level without any parentheses. So: a OR b AND c OR d AND e AND f. 

The list can contain any number of conditions with mixed operators(And, Or). 

Currently if I chain it together in Jooq as we discussed earlier it generates (a OR b) and c.. etc which is not what I want.

Comment: @ZoltánRaffai: OK, I get it. I feel like I answered your original question, which was more generic. I'll be happy to answer this additional question in a new question, as I will have to elaborate. The comments here won't suffice.

Comment: Okay, posted another one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78192807/jooq-order-precedence